# Addition and Subtraction of Convergent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a simple question and I can't find the answer of it: If a series $a_{n}$ can be proven to converge and a series $b_{n}$ too, will the series $a_{n}+b_{n}$ converge? Same goes with the subtraction of them.
Thank you

Comment: Just straightforwardly input everyhting in the $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ definition of the limit and compute what comes out.

Comment: Yes, always. However, the sum of a divergent and a divergent **can** sometimes converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ converge implies $\exists a,b $ such that given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon/2,|b_n-b|<\epsilon/2$ $\forall n\gt n_0$

Then, for $|a_n+b_n-(a+b)|\leq |a_n-a|+|b_n-b|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$

Therefore, $\{a_n+b_n\}$ converges to $a+b$

Comment: This is a good answer yet it may be the OP won't be able to see at once the relation between his question on series and this addressing *sequences* . Perhaps a little explanation about the sequence of partial sums of a series would be good.